# Two ways of searching for a prime

Tags: java, algorithm, math, primes

I understand why you only have to loop while `i*i <= n` in the following code:

```
public static boolean checkPrime1(int n){
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= n; i++){
        if(n%i==0)return false;
    } return true;
}
```

because one of the factors should be less than the square root of n.

But I was reading a book recently, and the condition or guard for the loop in a similar method was `i <= n/i`

```
public static boolean checkPrime(int n){
    for(int i = 2; i <= n/i; i++){
        if(n%i == 0)return false;
    } return true;
}
```

I know it's probably obvious to most people here, but can anyone simplify why the second condition works? I can't see how it's equivalent to the square root of n. would appreciate it

Comment: if i*i <= n, then i <= n/i, right?

Comment: It's a math problem, not a code one, vote to close

Comment: Divide is a slower operation than multiply, so the first code is faster.

Answer (score 3):

`i*i <= n` is exactly the same as `i <= n/i`.
Just do the math.

If `i` is positive, which it always is in this case, you can multiply or divide the condition with `i` and the operator (`<=`) will remain the same.

Comment: i really don't know why i didn't look at it like that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both are exactly same. Think it as a math operation. If `i=n/i` then `i*i=n`. Similarly here `i*i <= n` and `i <= n/i` both will give a same result.